# How do I access Watir properties of PageObject elements?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I'm new to PageObject, but I've used Watir before.  I have a Login class

```
class Login
  include PageObject

  page_url 'http://localhost:9090/#/login'

  button(:login, :id => 'login-btn')
end
```

I want to check whether the button is enabled.  Normally, I'd just call it in Watir with something like

```
@browser.button(:id => 'login-btn').enabled?
```

When I try to use the login PageObject alias, I get an error.

```
on(Login).login.enabled?
> NoMethodError: undefined method 'enabled?' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there a PageObject-flavored way to access Watir properties such as enabled, or do I need to manually find the element through the @browser variable and check it that way?  That seems to defeat the purpose of using PageObject to begin with.

Comment: The 'test-factory' gem allows for the kind of thing you wanted to do above, as it's more optimized around watir instead of trying to support both Watir and Selenium users.    If you are just getting started you might want to evaluate it as an alternative to the page-object gem.  If you have a lot of code already written then probably not worth switching horses mid-stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page object accessor methods, eg `button`, will create a `<name>_element` method that returns a `PageObject::Elements::Element`. With this object, you can inspect various aspects of the element.

For this case, the button state can be checked with:

```
on(Login).login_element.enabled?
```

Note that the `PageObject::Elements::Element` is a wrapper around the `Watir::Element`. This means that methods you used in Watir may not be available (ie not implemented). If you run into this situation, you can directly access the underlying `Watir::Element` using the `element` method.

```
on(Login).login_element.element.enabled?
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!